I need help obtaining a static IP address for my SIM card
I am currently experiencing a problem with my SIM card, supplied by KPN, which is unable to obtain a static IP address in a stable manner. Despite several attempts to configure it, the problem persists and this is affecting the connectivity of the device.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Manually configuring the IP address settings in the device settings.
Exploring the use of APM (Application Performance Monitoring), with no success in obtaining a stable static IP address.
At present, I'm continuing to run tests, but the kit is no longer able to connect to the Internet.
Have you encountered a similar problem or do you have any advice on how to resolve this? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Static IP, if available, must be from your service provider. It's not something users configure.

I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to have anything to do with using or administrating a Unix system. If your question is about an Android device, then you may try https://android.stackexchange.com instead.

As ChanganAuto said in the comment: that's impossible.
You can't just randomly assign an IP to a SIM (or rather, the device it works with), your ISP needs to assign it to you; how else would routing work if your provider doesn't know about said IP?
